# Error in converting Android Application to Android library

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am converting Android Application to Android Library. Conversion is successful but when I run `./gradlew build` or `./gradlew install` it is giving error

```
Execution failed for task ':sdk:installDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

sdk is library module name.
```

Error seems pretty clear that it is failing in `sdk:installDebugAndroidTest` but I don't know how to remove this task

Comment: How you convert application to library. What are the changes you make to create library project from application project

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.library', removed version and all from build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Android Library project we can't run.

1. Library project not having the Application Id. So I think it won't create the process for your library.
2. Library project  generating the .aar file instead of apk file.

You just modify the build.gradle (app) file.

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

       To

  apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

and remove the "application id" line in build.gradle file.

and clean the project and make project **(don't run)**

Comment: That's fine, but ./gradlew build command is supposed to create the aar file but it is throwing the error no connected devices :(